# OpenID Connect: How to maintain a single sign-on experience between multiple web clients of the same umbrella application?

Tags: security, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm considering how to take a fairly complex tiered application with multiple web apps that delegate back to the same application server, and migrate it to use OIDC authentication with auth code flow. I am anticipating using identity server 4.

My question is: what would be accepted best practice in terms of maintaining a single-sign-on experience between these different web client applications (i.e. user signs into one, she's signed into them all until she signs out).

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/why-use-access-tokens-to-secure-apis suggests:

> Note that the audience (aud claim) of the [id token] is set to the client's identifier, which means that only this specific client should consume this token.

This suggests that I should consider my backend application server to be my single 'client', and have my web apps share that same client ID. I can imagine doing this by storing the id token browser-side in a secure cookie.

https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect seems to validate this idea:

> Put into a browser cookie the ID token can be used to implement lightweight stateless sessions.

But I wonder if it's security best practice to keep an id_token in a cookie.

I wonder if there are any other approaches - like:

- Considering each web application a separate 'client'
- When the user logs on to a second web application, have them direct back to the OIDC provider, which would automatically create a client token for the new client based on some notion that they are still basically 'logged-on' to the OP.

It seems like this must be a solved problem. What is accepted best practice here?

Comment: So this is 2 different questions in one. First around UX with SSO, which should go UX exchange (or Software Engineering Exchange), second is around the security principles which should go to Software Engineering. Either way this is not the right exchange for this question.

Comment: @Aeseir there's only one of those two areas where I'm seeking information, which is security principles. The mention of UX is just to add context to what I'm trying to achieve - there's no 'extra question' there. And this stack has a lot more `opened-connect` questions than softwareengineering.SE, and is the recommended stack for `identityserver4`.

Comment: IdentityServer4 is but one implementation of openid connect, and you haven't asked a IdentityServer4 question nor demonstrated the code as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. What you have asked is opinion on security approach to openid connect, which is better answered in Software Engineering exchange. It is why i advised you to post this over there. Just friendly advice.

Comment: @Aeseir I appreciate the advice, just replying with my thoughts! :). It's not a code question - it's an approach question - which is why there's no code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic does clarify that questions with no code are fine, even if the main focus of SO is actual code. I'd be delighted if I could ask on another stack, but this is the one with the most `openid-connect` -tagged questions - there are *none* on Software Engineering. You're right that it isn't actually an identity server 4 specific question so I agree that the IS4 link isn't in itself a reason to ask here.

Comment: You are right about lack of openid-connect tags, i would use authentication and sso tag on SE exchange. SE has a lot less specifics but this i would definitely ask there, as it is a wider question around sso, approaches and best practices.

Comment: @Aeseir I've cross-posted to security.stackexchange.com - there are at least a few `openid-connect` -tagged questions there. Thanks.

Comment: if that doesn't work put one up on se exchange, pretty certain u will get a hit there

Comment: @Aeseir I will do... I have a few such questions so do want to find the best place to ask. Thanks.